# Crystallographic Groups Question

Tags: geometric-group-theory

A Crystallographic Group is a discrete group of isometries acting on the n-dimensional euclidean space $\mathbb{R} ^n $ with compact fundamental domain.

A lattice is a crystallographic group which consists only of translations.

We have a theorem that says that every crystallographic group contains n linearly independent translations.

Now, we take $L$ to be the subgroup of an n-dimensional crystallographic group $G$ consisting of all pure translations in G.

Does the first theorem I stated implies $L$ must be a lattice?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is a "pure translation"?

Comment: Is a pure translation is a translation, that looks like a tautology to me. Except that you must show that $n$ independent translations in dimension $n$ imply compact fundamental domain, but that is true as well.